# How to bypass a function with @functools.lru_cache decorator

Tags: python-3.x, caching

Hope you are doing well!

I'm using a function that is utilizing the lru_cache of functools library. for example:

```
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=pow(2,13))
def get_id(word):
    # retrieving id, using cache if possible
```

I would like on some occasions to bypass the cache, thus getting the ID straight from the source,
but I wouldn't like to create 2 separate functions (one with cache, and the other without) that are running exactly the same code.
Reading the documentation of functools on docs.python I understand that the cache can be bypassed:

> The original underlying function is accessible through the **wrapped**
> attribute. This is useful for introspection, for bypassing the cache,
> or for rewrapping the function with a different cache.

I've tried doing so with a wrapper function, but since the inner function exists only while the outer function was running, the cache was reset on every call.

I would appreciate any help on the matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what the documentation is telling you is that you can access the wrapped function directly this way (bypassing the caching):

```
get_id.__wrapped__(word="hello")
```

---

you could add one additional layer with a flag:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=pow(2, 13))
def get_cached(word):
    return get_raw(word)

def get_raw(word):
    # your logic goes here...
    pass

def get_id(word, cached=True):
    if cached:
        return get_cached(word)
    else:
        return get_raw(word)
```

Comment: Thank you, i actually tried using get_id.__wrapped__(parameters), but since the function was part of a class method one the parameters was "self", which i forgot about, thus made me think I wasn't using .__wrapped__ attribute the right way.